# Realm notification to RX block

Tags: ios, swift, realm, rx-swift

I would like to hide my Realm implementation and instead of working on `RLMNotificationBlock` I would like to use RXSwift. Below how my method looks like now (`RLMNotificationBlock` is a block that takes String and `RLMRealm`):

```
func addNotificationBlock(block: RLMNotificationBlock) -> RLMNotificationToken? {
    let rlmObject = ...
    return rlmObject.addNotificationBlock(block)
}
```

But I would like to switch to more reactive observer-pattern way. I looked at RxSwift docs and source code of `rx_clickedButtonAtIndex`, but I cannot figure out how I should put all these things together. I guess my code at the end would look like:

```
public var rx_realmContentChanged: ControlEvent<Int> {
    let controlEvent = ControlEvent()
    // My code go here
    return controlEvent
}
```

I'm new with RXSwift and know only the basics. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Realm and RxJava example is here https://realm.io/news/using-realm-with-rxjava/ I hope this helps. Important things are: use two models, RLMObject and plain Object. Because RLMResults cannot across threads. RealmDataService 1) executes queries and retrieve RLMResults 2) convert RLMResults to plain objects 3) output them to observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Rx Realm extension available on GitHub you can use: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm

It allows you to get an Observable out of a single Realm object or a Realm Collection. Here's an example from the README:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let laps = realm.objects(Lap.self))

Observable.changesetFrom(laps)
  .subscribe(onNext: { results, changes in
    if let changes = changes {
    // it's an update
    print(results)
    print("deleted: \(changes.deleted) inserted: \(changes.inserted) updated: \(changes.updated)")
  } else {
    // it's the initial data
    print(results)
  }
})
```

There is also an additional library especially built for binding table and collection views called RxRealmDataSources

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you just want to return `Observable<RLMNotificationToken>`
In this case you just need to do something like this

```
func addNotificationBlock(block: RLMNotificationBlock) -> Observable<RLMNotificationToken> {
    return create { observer -> Disposable in
        let rlmObject = ...
        let token = rlmObject.addNotificationBlock(block)

        // Some condition
        observer.onNext(token)
        // Some other condition
        observer.onError(NSError(domain: "My domain", code: -1, userInfo: nil))

        return AnonymousDisposable {
            // Dispose resources here
        }
        // If you have nothing to dipose return `NopDisposable.instance`
    }
}
```

In order to use it bind it to button rx_tap or other use `flatMap` operator